# Set all shipping methods cost to zero based on cart contents total amount in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, shipping-method

So I'm using this PHP snippet in order to give a free shipping to my customers when they have more than $60 in their cart.

```php
function wc_ninja_change_flat_rates_cost( $rates, $package ) {
    // Make sure flat rate is available
    if ( isset( $rates['flat_rate:1'] ) ) {
        // Current value of the shopping cart
        $cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->subtotal;

        // Check if the subtotal is greater than 60
        if ( $cart_subtotal >= 59.99 ) {
            // Set the cost to $0
            $rates['flat_rate:1']->cost = 0;
            $rates['flat_rate:2']->cost = 0;
            $rates['flat_rate:3']->cost = 0;
        }
    }
    

    return $rates;
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates', 'wc_ninja_change_flat_rates_cost', 10, 2 );
```

---

Currently if they have a product which cost $70 in the cart and apply a $20 coupon, they still receive a free shipping (because the subtotal is above $60).

I want to grant them a free shipping (set all shipping methods cost to zero) only if the amount is greater than $60 AFTER any discounts/coupons.

I already tried with:

```php
$cart_subtotal = WC()->cart->total;
```

But there is no difference, any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Using `WC()->cart->get_total()` will not give the desired result, because the output also contains HTML markup while you just need an integer, use `WC()->cart->cart_contents_total` instead.

It is also not necessary to define all shipping methods via code (`$rates['flat_rate:1']`, `$rates['flat_rate:']`, etc.. ), you can just loop through all available shipping methods and adjust them.

So you get:

```php
function filter_woocommerce_package_rates( $rates, $package ) {
    // Cart total amount (integer)
    $cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total;

    // Greater than or equal to
    if ( $cart_total >= 59.99 ) {
        foreach ( $rates as $rate_key => $rate ) {
            // For "free shipping" method (enabled), remove it
            if ( $rate->method_id == 'free_shipping' ) {
                unset( $rates[$rate_key] );
            // For other shipping methods
            } else {
                // Append rate label titles (free)
                $rates[$rate_key]->label .= ' ' . __( '(free)', 'woocommerce' );

                // Set rate cost
                $rates[$rate_key]->cost = 0;

                // Set taxes rate cost (if enabled)
                $taxes = array();

                foreach ( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes as $key => $tax ) {
                    if ( $rates[$rate_key]->taxes[$key] > 0 ) {
                        $taxes[$key] = 0;
                    }
                }

                $rates[$rate_key]->taxes = $taxes;
            }
        }
    }

    return $rates;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_package_rates','filter_woocommerce_package_rates', 10, 2 );
```

Don't forget to empty your cart to refresh shipping cached data!

---

My answer is largely based on [Set all shipping methods cost to zero for a Free shipping coupon in Woocommerce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48664864/11987538) answer code

Answer (score 0):

Try with:

```
 $cart_total = WC()->cart->get_total();
```